# Detect whether the image was taken from camera or loaded from gallery on html input file

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

On many smartphones an input file field its suggest to open the native camera, take picture and save.

Is it possible to know when the image was taken from camera or loaded from gallery?

Possible duplicate: [Detect whether the loading image is taken from camera directly, when using smartphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395371/detect-whether-the-loading-image-is-taken-from-camera-directly-when-using-smart)

Comment: Taking a picture usually saves an image to the gallery anyway so technically everything is uploaded from the gallery.  You could try seeing how recent the EXIF date is, but you would have time zone issues to deal with.

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for - if you already found duplicate why asking the question? (closed as duplicate you've suggested for now).